# Switch in Python Turtle Module

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to make a simple switch that changes a variable (in this case switchvalue) when I hit a key. My approach doesn't seem to be working, the key detection is working as far as I can tell.

```
import turtle
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()

jack = Turtle("turtle")
jack.color("red", "green")
jack.pensize(10)
jack.speed(0)
switchvalue = 1


def switch():
    global switchvalue
    if switchvalue == 1:
        switchvalue = 0
    if switchvalue == 0:
        switchvalue = 1




turtle.listen()

turtle.onkey(switch,"s")

screen.mainloop()

if switchvalue == 0:
    jack.forward(100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got your logic wrong at the function `switch()`. See what happens in the beggining when `switchvalue` is `1`

```
def switch():
    global switchvalue
    if switchvalue == 1: # True
        switchvalue = 0 # change it to 0
    if switchvalue == 0: # Whoops, True again, because you switched it to 0 before
        switchvalue = 1
```

As you can see you are changing `switchvalue` to `0` then checking if it is `0` and then it gets changed back to `1`, in other words both `if` statements are executed. You should instead use `elif` or `else` so that if one succeds the "`if` loop" (metaphorically speaking) will break aka the other `if`s will not be checked.

```
def switch():
    global switchvalue
    # IF one if succeds all the others will not be accounted
    if switchvalue == 1:
        switchvalue = 0
    elif switchvalue == 0:
        switchvalue = 1
```

Comment: My entire problem this whole time has been that I just forgot the elif. I really have to work on my memory.

Comment: @Zwiebelgian Always good practise to refer to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html).

Answer (score 0):

Even if you fix the `elif` issue that @Countour-Integral points out, this code isn't going to work.  Code after the `mainloop()` call isn't executed until after turtle shuts down, at which time `forward()` is meaningless:

```
screen.mainloop()

if switchvalue == 0:
    jack.forward(100)
```

You're mixing the *functional* API of turtle with its *object-oriented* API which is why you need your double `import` of turtle:

```
import turtle
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
```

This only leads to trouble.  Let's rewrite the program to use just the object-oriented API and actually work:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

switchvalue = True

def switch():
    global switchvalue

    switchvalue = not switchvalue

def move():
    delay = 100  # if not moving, slow for human intervention

    if switchvalue:
        jack.forward(1)
        delay = 0  # moving, check back right away

    screen.ontimer(move, delay)  # delay in milliseconds

screen = Screen()

jack = Turtle('turtle')
jack.color('red', 'green')
jack.speed('fastest')
jack.pensize(10)

screen.onkey(switch, 's')
screen.listen()

move()

screen.mainloop()
```

When the program starts, the turtle will be wandering off to the right.  By pressing 's', you can stop and restart this motion.

Comment: This was not the real code, i just simplified it so it's easier and faster to read through, thank you anyways